# how add an array to another array that exist in an object in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

here is my schema

```
    const CustomerSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
    purchased: {
      modelsId: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId ,
        trim: true,
      }],
      collectionsId: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        trim: true,
      }]
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

and i want to add an array to modelsId array in purchased object with mongoose

```
Customer.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: customer._id }, { $addToSet: { 'purcased.modelsId': { $each: modelsId } } }, 
{ new: true }).then(res => {
                        console.log('response', res)
                    }).catch(e => {
                        console.log('error', e)
                    })
```

and it's not working!
thank you for your help!

Comment: modelsId = ["5faee4ed9c90235da7765f32","5faee69b9c90235da7765f33"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may just have a simple spelling error? Try changing `'purcased.modelsId'` to `'purchased.modelsId'`. You're just missing an 'h' I think!